# HTML CSS Grid-Container Automatically Scroll to desired element

Tags: html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have created a one row, grid container with 31 columns to act as a horizontally scrolling date picker. It works great.
However, I am struggling to have the grid-container automatically scroll to the correct element depending on today's date. Currently when I open it, the grid starts at item 0 in view and then I have to scroll to the correct element manually.

Any ideas on how I can do this? Do I need to use the index of the data array which is being used to populate each grid-item?

Here is the CSS

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(31, calc(50% - 80px));
    grid-template-rows: minmax(100px, 1fr);
    overflow: scroll;
    grid-column-gap: 8px;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

Here is the data array using Vue

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item" :id="day.date" v-for="day in days" :key="day.date">
        <div v-if="availDays.includes(day.dayName) && day.fullDate >= getToday" @click="datePicked(day.date)" class="available">
            <p>{{day.dayName}}</p>

            <p>{{day.date}}</p>
        </div>
        <div v-else @click="clearTimes(day.date)" class="notAvailable">
            <p>{{day.dayName}}</p>

            <p>{{day.date}}</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```